# consumer didnt consume till i change the groupid

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

hi i'm have written a kafka consumer using spirng-kafka. It simply consume 3 topics. I was using one groupid for all the topics.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", groupId = "myConsumer")
```

Till yesterday i was able to consume messages without any issue. But today my consumer didnt consume any messages. I haven't done anything to the codebase to break the flow. But it didnt work like it used to be. When i checked the logs when i started the app, i saw below log.

```
2022-09-22 15:32:01.014  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Disconnecting from node -1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 8403 ms.
2022-09-22 15:32:01.017  WARN 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Bootstrap broker myMSKserver.com:9098 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2022-09-22 15:32:01.870  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Disconnecting from node -2 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 9242 ms.
2022-09-22 15:32:01.870  WARN 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Bootstrap broker myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2022-09-22 15:32:02.039  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Disconnecting from node -1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 9380 ms.
2022-09-22 15:32:02.039  WARN 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Bootstrap broker myMSKserver.com:9098 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2022-09-22 15:32:02.801  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Disconnecting from node -2 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 10220 ms.
2022-09-22 15:32:02.801  WARN 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Bootstrap broker myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2022-09-22 15:32:03.283  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Disconnecting from node -3 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 10708 ms.
2022-09-22 15:32:03.283  WARN 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Bootstrap broker myMSKserver2.com:9098 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2022-09-22 15:32:05.121  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Cluster ID: bJ_O-xqmRRGAsq0hF6QKcw
2022-09-22 15:32:05.159  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Cluster ID: bJ_O-xqmRRGAsq0hF6QKcw
2022-09-22 15:32:05.165  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Discovered group coordinator myMSKserver.com:9098 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
2022-09-22 15:32:05.167  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:05.261  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Discovered group coordinator myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2022-09-22 15:32:05.262  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Cluster ID: bJ_O-xqmRRGAsq0hF6QKcw
2022-09-22 15:32:05.263  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:05.309  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Discovered group coordinator myMSKserver2.com:9098 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2022-09-22 15:32:05.311  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:05.666  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Cluster ID: bJ_O-xqmRRGAsq0hF6QKcw
2022-09-22 15:32:05.696  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Cluster ID: bJ_O-xqmRRGAsq0hF6QKcw
2022-09-22 15:32:05.768  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Discovered group coordinator myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2022-09-22 15:32:05.770  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:11.911  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-09-22 15:32:11.912  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:11.926  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-09-22 15:32:11.926  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:11.981  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-09-22 15:32:11.981  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:13.283  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-09-22 15:32:13.283  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Discovered group coordinator myMSKserver.com:9098 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
2022-09-22 15:32:13.283  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:13.286  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:13.788  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=119, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2-989a1cec-5de3-4d58-aa84-cb18aae0171f', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:14.180  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=119, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2-989a1cec-5de3-4d58-aa84-cb18aae0171f', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:14.183  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[])
2022-09-22 15:32:14.183  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-2-2, groupId=myConsumer-retry-2] Adding newly assigned partitions: 
2022-09-22 15:32:14.184  INFO 36384 --- [3-retry-2-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : myConsumer-retry-2: partitions assigned: []
2022-09-22 15:32:14.311  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=117, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5-c702bf41-6422-408e-bbdb-28be1219228d', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:14.551  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=1020, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1-40217070-e198-44cd-9242-d08a050705a2', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:14.575  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=121, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4-07260bb1-10ef-4842-9ba5-5aa35b474b8e', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:14.878  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=121, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4-07260bb1-10ef-4842-9ba5-5aa35b474b8e', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:14.880  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-retry-1-0])
2022-09-22 15:32:14.882  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Adding newly assigned partitions: epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-retry-1-0
2022-09-22 15:32:15.067  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=117, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5-c702bf41-6422-408e-bbdb-28be1219228d', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.069  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[])
2022-09-22 15:32:15.069  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-0-5, groupId=myConsumer-retry-0] Adding newly assigned partitions: 
2022-09-22 15:32:15.069  INFO 36384 --- [1-retry-0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : myConsumer-retry-0: partitions assigned: []
2022-09-22 15:32:15.166  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=1020, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1-40217070-e198-44cd-9242-d08a050705a2', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.167  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-dlt-0])
2022-09-22 15:32:15.167  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Adding newly assigned partitions: epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-dlt-0
2022-09-22 15:32:15.605  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-retry-1-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: 3 rack: use1-az2)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.605  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-retry-1-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=58, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: 3 rack: use1-az2)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.605  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-retry-1-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver.com:9098 (id: 2 rack: use1-az4)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.605  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-retry-1-4, groupId=myConsumer-retry-1] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-retry-1-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=2, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver2.com:9098 (id: 1 rack: use1-az1)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.708  INFO 36384 --- [2-retry-1-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : myConsumer-retry-1: partitions assigned: [epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-retry-1-0, epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-retry-1-0]
2022-09-22 15:32:15.878  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-09-22 15:32:15.879  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] (Re-)joining group
2022-09-22 15:32:15.918  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-dlt-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=8, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver2.com:9098 (id: 1 rack: use1-az1)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.918  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-dlt-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=82, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver.com:9098 (id: 2 rack: use1-az4)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.918  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-dlt-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=85, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: 3 rack: use1-az2)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.918  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-dlt-1, groupId=myConsumer-dlt] Setting offset for partition epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-dlt-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=5, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[myMSKserver1.com:9098 (id: 3 rack: use1-az2)], epoch=8}}
2022-09-22 15:32:15.919  INFO 36384 --- [ner#4-dlt-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : myConsumer-dlt: partitions assigned: [epdcs.dev.assignments_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.itemsessions_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.assignmentattempts_outbox-dlt-0, epdcs.dev.itemattempts_outbox-dlt-0]
2022-09-22 15:32:17.876  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=1016, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-3-63d1b7b8-8450-45bf-bcf1-e9936c9aca28', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:18.185  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=1016, memberId='consumer-myConsumer-3-63d1b7b8-8450-45bf-bcf1-e9936c9aca28', protocol='range'}
2022-09-22 15:32:18.185  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[])
2022-09-22 15:32:18.185  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myConsumer-3, groupId=myConsumer] Adding newly assigned partitions: 
2022-09-22 15:32:18.185  INFO 36384 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : myConsumer: partitions assigned: []
```

In this log, i noticed this -> partitions assigned: []

So i changed the groupId and started the application again and then it worked without any issue. Below log is a log line that i retrieved from the new application startup log with the new groupId.

```
myConsumer_new: partitions assigned: [topic1-0, topic2-0, topic3-0, topic4-0]
```

Can someone please explain me the reason for that ?

and if i want to use my previous groupid, what should i do?

Comment: 1) Was there actually any records to consume 2) Was there already a client in the same consumer group?

Comment: no actually, there were no clients with the same group and yes, there were some records to consume. To double check i published some data manually to some of those topics. But nothing consumed.

Comment: biggest concern i have is, in the log it shows that  partitions assigned: [] for the old consumer group. Usually that array should have some values. But in there it is empty

Comment: Can you run `kafka-consumers-groups --describe` to see if Kafka thinks there are other clients in the group?